# ¿Cómo hacer ZOOM a un elemento <Image> de un SVG sin perder las coordenadas?

Tags: css

Quiero hacer ZOOM a  dentro de un SVG pero al usar transform: scale() pierde las coordenadas originales

```
<svg>
   <image>Quiero hacer ZOOM a este elemento</image>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asegúrate de aplicarle antes una propiedad `transition` para luego darle el efecto con `hover`:

```
.zoom {
    transition: transform .2s; 
}
 
.zoom:hover {
    transform: scale(1.5); 
}
```

Si aún no te funciona, podrías guiarte del siguiente [ejemplo](https://codepen.io/christopher-ps/pen/zYWxJjg) que tengo preparado.